# How to display number as currency when using a CASE statement in SQL

Tags: mysql

The number is being displayed is a long set up numbers after the decimal point.

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN phonecalls_type = 'NATIONAL' THEN phonecalls_duration*0.5666666667
WHEN phonecalls_type = 'MOBILE' THEN phonecalls_duration*0.76666666667
ELSE phonecalls_duration*0
END AS CallCost
FROM phonecalls
WHERE phonecalls_calling LIKE '$FNN' 
ORDER BY phonecalls_datetime ASC
```

Needing to have the 'phonecalls' display in currency format ie $1.56 rather than 156.68268525

Answer (score 0):

you could use a proper format

```
FORMAT( CASE 
WHEN phonecalls_type = 'NATIONAL' THEN phonecalls_duration*0.5666666667
WHEN phonecalls_type = 'MOBILE' THEN phonecalls_duration*0.76666666667
ELSE phonecalls_duration*0
END, 2)
```

or

```
CONCAT('$', FORMAT( CASE 
  WHEN phonecalls_type = 'NATIONAL' THEN phonecalls_duration*0.5666666667
  WHEN phonecalls_type = 'MOBILE' THEN phonecalls_duration*0.76666666667
  ELSE phonecalls_duration*0
  END, 2) )
```

Comment: You should be closing these questions as duplicates